# getting tag within div class with one line JS

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to JS. I have

```
<div class="test-button-set">
  <button id="hdfs_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HDFS</button>
  <button id="hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE</button>
  <button id="hdfs_hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH</button>
</div>
```

I want to get all my `<button>` elements in an array. I know I can do `var j = document.getElementsByClassName("test-button-set")[0]` then do a `j.getElementsByTagName("button")` to get the buttons. I was wondering if there was a way where I could do all this in one line of code.

Comment: What browsers does this need to work in?

Comment: @SeanVieira as many as possible? would be nice but I know IE has some issues especially the older versions so I guess I'm not too worried about this as long as it works on the more recently used browsers

Comment: Where do you believe you can add a one line of code? In the HTML `onload onclick`? In a `script` tag/file? On the buttons (which I hope you wouldn't) ... ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're specifically trying to get back? Given the div with class 'test-button-set', are you trying to get a specific button tag inside of it?

Comment: What do you mean you want to get <button> in an array?

Comment: Couldn't you just chain the functions, like `document.getElementsByClassName("test-button-set")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")`?

Comment: @sphanley youre right i can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you only need to support [old to recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) (not everything back to IE 4) you can just use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.test-button-set button');
```

Alternatively, if you need to only get the buttons that are a descendent of the *first* `.test-button-set`:

```
var buttons = document.querySelector('.test-button-set').getElementsByTagName('button')
```

Answer (score 3):

how abt this?

```
var buttons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".test-button-set > button"));
```

this will give you all of the desired buttons in an actual array rather than a nodelist

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accomplish the same outcome you're getting with your two lines of code without using querySelector/querySelectorAll (which is a great option but isn't supported in some older browsers), you could just chain your methods together to get them on one line rather than using a variable and breaking them up onto two:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test-button-set")[0].getElementsByTagName("but‌​ton")
```